# Excel: Formula to place a random number in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

This one has got me seriously stumped, so I thought I'd share it with you guys and see what I get :)

### General Problem

I have the following data in a spreadsheet[image: Data Array]

As you can see I have two identical sets of headings 'Cat, Dog, Man...' (the precise names do not matter)

These two sets are classed under either the 'From' column or the 'To' row.
The bulk of the table is an array of numbers between 0 and 1, or empty cells.

Essentially what I want to do is find where a given `Rand()` number ranks along each **row**. I then return the item from the 'To' row corresponding to where the random number would be placed.

*i.e.* Reading along the 1st **Cat** row, a random number (between 1 and 0 too) is ranked. If it's,say, between 0 and 0.3658... I return Cat, 0.7193... and 1 gives me Van

So *ideally* I return the value from the **To** set of headings which is vertically above the upper bound within which the `Rand()` number lies.

---

### Attempted Solution

To achieve this ranking I've been using the `Match(value,array,0)` function (0 as my numbers are in ascending order).

A simplified version of my formula is therefore:

`=Index(To_Headings,MATCH(RAND(),From_Row,0))`

where `To_Headings` is the array `E3:I3` and `From_Row` is an array I generate using a further formula, resulting in `D#:I#` *(# being a row number which is related to the **From** headings, so must be an integer between 4 and 8)*

**However if you are particularly observant, you can see this is where my solution falls short**

As I say,*ideally* I want to find the upper bound of where RAND() lies, as this is always in the same column as my desired output **To** heading. `MATCH()` with a parameter of 0 returns the lower bound of where `RAND()` lies. Typically this is the column 1 to the left of the desired column.

*e.g.* Reading along the **Cat** row again - for a random number of 0.5, bounds within which it lies are 0.3658... and 0.7193... .The upper bound is directly below **Dog**, my desired output. The lower is 1 column to the left of the desired 1, so in my formula I simply shift back to the right when reading off using `Index`

[image: Image repeated for reference]

HOWEVER the blank cells render this useless. For a random number between 0.719... and 1, the lower bound is now **two** columns to the left of the upper bound. In other instances it can be 3 or 4, in fact any number. This is because the blank cells *push* the upper bound further right.

---

Right, bearing all that in mind, can anyone tell me how to rank the RAND() number so it gives me the upper bound? Of course I've tried Match with -1 as the parameter, however because that requires descending order the problem flips too!

I'm thinking I could try counting if there are any blanks to the right of the lower bound, and offsetting my `INDEX` by that many instead of just 1, but I can see that will add a lot of lines to my code, and I really need to keep it streamlined, as it will be running in about 10000 cells!!

Comment: Have you considered using VBA?

Comment: I have considered it, but avoided for two reasons;
1)I'm pretty much a complete novice on VBA, so wouldn't be able to do it myself without some serious time invested in learning it, and also wouldn't be able to quickly alter solutions if they were written for me.
2)I feel like I'm so close with this, and have enough experience with formulae to know it's possible, that switching to VBA seems like a bit of a cop out + adds annoying implementation problems (macros always feel less automatic to me)

Comment: Fair enough, especially with the learning curve part. But at some stage it might be a good time investment. There is a limit to what can be achieved with built-in functions. If the logic is too involved it won't be possible, and even if it is possible, the deeply-nested formulas required rapidly become unreadable. On the other hand, a formula guru like @ScottCraner often surprises me in showing how much can be done without VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this array formula.

Since your data is arranged in ascending order, this will find the first cell in which the random number is less than or equal to the number in the dataset:

```
=INDEX($E$3:$I$3,MATCH(TRUE,$J$2<=E4:I4,0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

I've found another very simple answer through experiment with the `Match` function.

All you have to do is fill those blanks with the number on the left. Since `Match` doesn't look for the first instance of a number greater than the random number, but instead the *last*, by filling in the blanks all the adjustment is done for you.

So the example picture now becomes the following:
[image: DataSet2]

So for example, reading along the **Cat** row again, 0.719... is repeated. For a random input of 0.8, instead of stopping at the **Dog** column as before (since 0.8<1, therefore 0.719... is the biggest number smaller than the random input), the formula now stops 1 column to the left of the Upper bound every time.

Now I admit @ScottCraner gave a perfect answer to my problem as stated, however an Array formula is stuck to only one size (without VBA) whereas cell formulae can automatically fill a new range, so for my application I cannot use that answer. So I thought I'd add on this solution as a cell formula approach.

Comment: What was the final formula?  And if my answer, answered the question as it was asked it should be marked as correct.  Changing the parameters after an answer is given is not usually acceptable.  A new question should be asked.  It is possible to make the range dynamic, but more information would be needed.  If you stated that the range may change then I could have given a better answer.

Comment: Yes @Scott, I see I should have given you the opportunity. I'll summarize; My formula goes in x columns, each y rows long. Whereas your array formula sees which row of numbers to place the random number in based on which row the formula is in (ie. in your array the 1st row ranks the random number in the **Cat** row), my formula looks in the row with the same title as the contents of the cell directly to its left. Also in my formula each cell has its own associated random number, as opposed to 1 number for the entire set of comparisons.

Comment: Now that may be possible to replicate with an array formula, I don't know. But I feel you would need more detail as my problem is quite a bit more complex than the example suggests. Given that the answer I provided means that in my checking cells I don't need to alter my formula at all, and in the array of numbers my formula actually gets _simpler_, I thought I'd leave the question at that. I felt further detail to pursue your approach would make your answer too specific to be useful to other users, and having solved the problem quite nicely I didn't think I needed a more precise answer.

Comment: On a side note, I did intend to mark your answer as correct, as 1) It neatly solves the problem as I presented it, & 2) I think it will be more useful for people with a similar problem than my situation-specific answer.

I only hadn't done so until now, as I have a habit of leaving questions for a day or two to accumulate further thoughts/alternative answers. I hope all that's (relatively) clear!

Comment: What is the specific formula it wl tell me more than a description. Please post the exact formula.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, I'll post my 2 formulae to take a look at, although I feel it might be difficult to understand exactly what's going on, especially because of all of my named ranges, but perhaps you will be able.
In my array of numbers: `=IF(OR($S13="",U$12=""),"",IFNA(IF($S13=U$12,1-INDEX(Table5[[Decay Limit]:[Decay Limit]],MATCH($S13,Table5[[Match]:[Match]],0))+[@A],IFNA(INDEX(Table5[[Decay Bound]:[Decay Bound]],MATCH($S13&U$12,Table5[[Concat]:[Concat]],0))+[@A],[@A])),1))`

Comment: And in my 'checking cells':

`=INDEX(SpeciesTo,MATCH(MIN(RAND(),1-10^(-16)),INDIRECT(CONCAT("UI!",ADDRESS(MATCH(G2,SpeciesFrom,0)+ROW(SpeciesAnchor),COLUMN(SpeciesAnchor)+1),":",ADDRESS(MATCH(G2,SpeciesFrom,0)+ROW(SpeciesAnchor),COLUMN(UI!$AM$12)))),1))`

Comment: Finally, to save explaining all of the naming, and what links to what, here's the spreadsheet [link](itself:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3SiQeLg3IBmYV9NNzVpVzRmUDA/view?usp=sharing). If you need to take a look, the relevant sheets are UI and Function. Anything else, just ask.